# Setting image's build action property

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I have simple problem. I want to add image to buttons and there is one case I can't manage. In designer everything works properly, but in debug mode there is no trace of a picture inside the button. I read that I have to set Build Action property of the image to "Recourses" or "Content" but I don't have these pictures in Solution Explorer, exactly I can see them when I click "Show All Files but they have strange icon not as the one image which I can normally see in Solutions Explorer and no Build Action property.

Am I supposed to add images in different way?

```
<Button x:Name="loadButton" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="955,0,0,443" Style="{DynamicResource SimpleButton}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="29" Height="27" FontFamily="Courier New" FontWeight="Bold" Click="loadButton_Click" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}">


        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image x:Name="Load" Source="open-map.png"/>
        </StackPanel>

    </Button>
    <CheckBox x:Name="mode" Content="Tryb tworzenia" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="30,292,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="18.667" Foreground="#FFAC3333" FontFamily="Courier New" IsChecked="True"/>
    <Button x:Name="button1_Copy" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="912,0,0,443" Style="{DynamicResource SimpleButton}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="29" Height="27" FontFamily="Courier New" FontWeight="Bold" Click="button1_Copy_Click" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}">

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image x:Name="Save" Source="save-icon.png"/>
        </StackPanel>

    </Button>
```

[image: Solution Explorer]

Thank in advanced

Comment: Please do not show your code as a picture.  Edit your question to replace it by code cut and pasted from the IDE. Once you have, select it and press Ctrl-K to format it as a code block.

Comment: Sorry I forgot about that, but i have edited question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files like open-map.png are not part of the C# project so you can't set any properties. Right click on the C# project and add the file to the project, then you'll be able to set its properties.